# Cannot open Visual Studio - throw error 'cannot run when setup is in progress'

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to open Visual Studio, but it is giving an error:

> cannot run when set up is in progress

It was running fine before when I restarted my machine. I have already installed this version from past one year.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It migth be that Visual Studio is being upgraded by Windows Update (patch http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45326&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_devresources) as a critical patch was released a few days ago... Not sure if it get's forced through Windows Update though... It might also be the installation of http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3002339

Comment: @jessehouwing Could be that Microsoft is simply attempting to force everyone to upgrade to Update 4, but however I have Update 3 on Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (yes, it's genuine and legally obtained via Microsoft's Dreamspark programme) and can confirm that it's not showing this message for me.

Comment: Check your Windows Update history to see if it's trying (and failing) to install a Visual Studio patch. Generally starting any Visual studio (update|patch) installer will prevent any instance of visual studio to start.

Comment: On 2018-03-19, this happened to me with Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (15.6.2).  Task Manager revealed a VSIXAutoUpdate.exe was running.  I probably have some Extensions with the "automatically update" checkbox set, which probably explains why I could not start VS 2017.  Once that extension auto updater finished, I was then able to start Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (15.6.2).

Comment: Typical MS approach... jam updates down your throat whether you want them or not.

Comment: For me it was visual studio code, after closing that VS worked fine

Comment: It's a typical crappy VS error. It looks like a catastrophic failure but it's just waiting until some updates are installed. Once they have finished it loads. It would be helpful if the message advised this.

Comment: Instead of breaking any process, waiting for a while to let it finish might be better. For me, it has been fixed by itself after a while later. As mentioned in a comment below `VSIXAutoUpdate` finished by itself.

Comment: Same, after 30 seconds the problem resolved itself. Very bizarre approach by VS team here.

Answer (score 181):

Try to check [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) and kill any process related to Visual Studio (any version).

**Update:**
as many people mentioned in the comments it could be better to wait a while until those processes end themselves

Comment: Surely this will allow you to start VS immediately. But aborting an update process may lead to failures. Better wait 3 minutes (until VSIXAutoUpdate.exe closes itself) and try again.

Comment: Now it says "The setup for the visual studio installation is not complete. Please run the visual studio installer again" lol

Comment: Yea. Probably not a great idea to kill process while they doing updated, eh? If the process doesnt stop just restart the PC and try again, restart will gracefully stop any processes instead of just killing it

Comment: This is shouldn't be an answer and shouldn't be up-voted!

Comment: The update is correct, after waiting for a while the processes finished by themselves.

Comment: This *seems* to occur when also the "Windows Module Installer" process is running. Maybe it is a resource bottleneck or some sort of lock issue...
Just waiting a couple of minutes always resolves it.

Comment: Go to Windows Update and Check for Updates. VSIXAutoUpdate closed by itself and I could open Visual Studio.

Comment: I have a situation where VSIXAutoUpdate.exe will be hung for a couple of hours and not finish. It just sits in the task manager consuming 0 CPU and a little bit of memory. Killing the process or restarting my computer both results in a corrupted visual studio installation forcing me to have to do a repair. From now on I will be disabling automatic updates of visual studio extensions cause this is absurd and it's the second time I have had to do this in the past month.

Comment: Edge installer in my case

Answer (score 139):

I had this problem with Visual Studio 2017. There were processes in Task Manager named `VSIXAutoUpdate.exe`. I watched Task Manager and they were spawning and despawning. A few times, a Visual Studio 2017 process would spawn and despawn.

After VSIX Auto Updater stopped showing up in Task Manager, it had applied all of it's background updates and I was able to launch Visual Studio.

I wouldn't recommend killing these processes in the middle of them installing updates, like other answers to this question suggest. Just wait until they finish by watching Task Manager.

Comment: Yes waiting is a good option, after 2-3 minutes it's starting properly. But I did not get this popup until last week. SInce then, it occurs every day (?) on only 1 of my 2 machines with VS (?) both have an updated W10, so..

Comment: Had a situation where the VSIX Auto Updater would start and just sit there doing noting. Ending it fixed the problem. I assume it was stuck trying to complete a failing install.

Comment: Yes, I just waited a bit until no processes showed any more.. Like 3 minutes (brewed up) and it started fine.

Comment: I waited, reading this post. By the time I read this comment I was able to open VS2017

Comment: I am using VS2019, and the background process is `VSIXConfigurationUpdater.exe`, just wait about 3 minutes. The process will exit automatically.

Comment: I have this problem in VS2019 and after 30 mins the process has not ended.

Answer (score 60):

Not exactly an answer to the original question, but if you *really* need to run VS during setup, you can use the undocumented `/AllowDuringSetup` command line switch (at your own risk).

Answer (score 42):

This happened to me when I attempted to fire up Visual Studio just after start up.

I couldn't see any Visual Studio or installer processes running in [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager), but I waited 5 minutes or so, tried again, and it opened.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me too. I killed any process I thought could be related and nothing. After reading this I tried launching it again and it just worked.

Comment: Genuinely just happened to me as described. Hadn't launched VS and there was nothing in Task Manager Visual Studio-ey. Just tried launching it again. Bingo. *shrug*

Comment: I restarted my system, waited for more than 30 mins,I checked task manager no process is running,  but still I am getting error message.

Comment: this happened after my first reboot from installing 20H2, 19042.662. SMH. This OS gets stranger every year.

Answer (score 30):

**Root Cause:**
If, We shutdown the system with out closing the visual studio properly and next time we will open the system then some times we will get this issue due to setup will run at background.

**Fix:**
No need to do any thing just wait for 10 to 15 minutes and open the visual studio again. It will automatically fix the issue.

Answer (score 29):

I encountered this error today after a cold boot (on a VM) and found a solution.

- Windows > Services
- Look for a service with a name like 'Visual Studio Standard Collector Service'
- Right click on the item and start the service => Visual Studio should now be able to launch

To prevent this from happening the next time you reboot (at least until there is an update that re-introduces the bug) you can:

- Right click on the item and select Properties
- Set the Startup type to 'Automatic'
- Select Apply

Found using: VS Community 2019, Version 16.1.3

Comment: This solution worked for me with VS2017, I had two of the 'Visual Studio Collector Service' (VS2015 installed too) so I selected the one with the description ending with 150 and then VS2017 fired up and loaded cached data (didn't pay attention to what the cache was). Didn't get the option to do a auto startup on Window 7. Closed Task Manager, reopen and the service was gone.

Comment: This answer is the only one that saved me.  Thank you, sir!

Comment: worked like a champ. vs2019. thanks...

Comment: It's late 2021 with an updated version of VS2019 and this still is an issue - but this step solved my case. Thank you great human!

Comment: I had the VSIXAutoUpdate.exe process running that other answers have mentioned. When I started the collector service, that process ended and I was able to open VS.

Answer (score 11):

Solution: Do not just open up Task Manager and Kill all processes that VSXAutoUpdate.exe is updating, this will give you problems when you try to start Visual Studio as updates were not complete. Instead, Wait until the update completes that is when you start the Visual Studio. If you no longer need the Visual Studio Component that is updating more regularly, again it is advised to uninstall the component via Visual Studio Installer

Answer (score 9):

Try restarting your computer.  That worked for me.

Comment: several times i have restarted my PC but its doesn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

Go to task manager and end the VS Auto Update task. It will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Open Task manager and stop the Visual Studio Process.

```
Clear out %temp% folder, and re-started VS2019.
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

It happended to me, I restarted the system but made no difference. Went to `Task Manager` and there was a task `VSIXAutoUpdate.exe` running. 
I could have just killed it, but I waited for like 10 minutes and tried again opening the `Visual Studio` and it worked.
Now you know what to do!

Comment: possibly crash visual studio while interrupting in between.

Answer (score 5):

A **pending Windows update** was the cause. After the Windows update Visual Studio starts without any problems.

Comment: Yes. This. <sarcasm mode>Thank you @Microsoft. Now I cannot do any work until the (automatic and not so optimal) update process is finished. It's not like people have deadlines or so.</sarcasm mode>

Answer (score 4):

Go to Task Manager. Under processes look for vns. Click End Process.

Answer (score 4):

I get this error message when an update has been pushed to Visual Studio, but failed for some reason.

To fix this, follow the steps below (Windows)

Settings > Apps > Visual Studio Installer > Click 'Modify'

You should see an error message saying something like "Updates could not be applied" and you can click the button to retry.

In my latest instance, it was a small update to the .NET Desktop Development Workload that hadn't downloaded or installed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely Visual Studio is being updated as the error message insinuates and if you wait a few minutes for the update to finish you should be able to run Visual Studio again without problems.

If the problem persists or if you're just curious, open up your task manager and see if there is anything related to (Microsoft) Visual Studio running but don't just kill the process. Check instead if the process is using any resources - if it has a high I/O count, then it's actually updating and you should let it do its thing. If CPU-usage and memory usage remain mostly constant and there is no disk activity for the process for several minutes, this could mean that the process is stuck. You might have to kill it, but proceed with caution. Hopefully if this is an update for Visual Studio, the process name should include a version number or some sort of indication of what kind of update is being applied that you can use to search for more information through a search engine or through Microsoft's online resources.

Comment: That worked for me... I was looking in the Task Manager to see what I could kill to try again and I noticed a running process ended and vanished from the list. It was in the right position to be part of the VS updater, so I figured what the hell and tried to launch it... kicked off just fine.

Answer (score 3):

If none of the aforementioned solutions help (which was the case for me), I've got another suggestion. Go to the control panel, and under "Programs and Features", click "Uninstall a Program".

You'll get this big window with all of your installed applications in it. If you tried to install an SDK or something and the program stopped working after that, find all the Visual Studio-related programs with an installation date that is the same as the date you began encountering the issue. Right click them, and if a 'Repair' option is available, click that. If not, click 'Uninstall', and then, in the window that opens after that, click 'Repair'.

So essentially, you're repairing everything Visual Studio-related that was installed on the same day you began seeing issues. It worked for me after installing an Azure SDK and seeing this error.

Comment: Thanks man! This solved my issue with VS2017. I suspect PC shutdown during updates, leaving unfinished installation.

Comment: awesome dude - my setup was interrupted by sudden power-down and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

- Give some time and try again.
- End all the tasks related to visual studio in task manager.
- If both of these solutions doesn't work then restart the machine it'll definitely work.

Answer (score 3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w99t.png)
Open the Task manager, there is a service named VSStandardCollectorService150 service, right-click to start it.
This is worked for me for the same issue on VS2019.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My problem was VSIXAutoUpdate. I had waited until the end of the processing. You can see VSIXAutoUpdate in Task Manager (Ctrl + Alt + Del).
VSIAutoupdate could be a malware sometimes so you must check details inside the properties in Task Manager (right click on VSIXAutoUpdate).
You can see the web page below:

https://www.file.net/process/vsixautoupdate.exe.html

Answer (score 2):

What I found on Task Manager was that a VS Preview 2019 version was updating while I was trying to start my production version of VS2017. Never had the problem before. I waited, as many others suggest, about 3 minutes and the problem subsided with not consequential repercussions. Felt a LOT better that way rather than nuking a task through Task Manager. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I cleared out my %temp% folder, and re-started VS2017.
started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue when opening `Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.4.2` inside my VM.

Here is the solution and this is what I did and it worked for me:

> **Don't kill any process related to Visual Studio in Task Manager as it may end in unexpected behavior and even make you to reinstall
>   Visual Studio sometimes. So Simply wait for 5 to 10 minutes. All the
>   process related to Visual Studio will end automatically.**

Now open your visual studio it will work normally.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the %temp% folder worked for me for the same issue on VS2019.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of killing VSIXAutoUpdate.exe, you should be able to prevent it from starting as it seems to be run by the task scheduler. Go to the Microsoft/VisualStudio folder in the scheduler and you will see one or more tasks called VSIX Auto Update (I guess there's one for each VS version installed). Right click and disable... You'll probably lose the ability for VS extensions to get automatically updated, though - hopefully nothing more than that.

Answer (score 2):

I have opened visual studio installer, clicked Modify, and launched the Visual Studio . It solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Press Win+R and type `%temp%` then delete all files, and restart Visual studio.
[image]

Check "**Do this for all items**" and press **Skip button** if required.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I found to 'EASE' the suffering is to open win 10 task manager and right click VSIXAutoUpate.exe, in context menu select go to details, right click the VSIXAutoUpate.exe again and in context menu select set priority and select realtime...... as I said this is to Ease the suffering not to end it

Comment: vs studio updates are suffering. facing the same issue today

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue today(VS 2015 update 3). Noticed that the service "VSStandardCollectorService140" was stopped. (I had a blue screen error when i logged of yesterday. May be something related to that) . Restarted this service and it's working

Answer (score 1):

You can also just launch Visual Studio Installer. The installer seems to fix whatever is the background issue. You can then just launch your Visual Studio from the installer.

I just now resolved my issue this way.

Answer (score 1):

I started Windows Installer service from the windows task manager then the Visual Studio 2019 opened
(solution suggested [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/317884/cannot-run-when-setup-is-in-progress-upon-launchin-1.html) and worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the "vs_installershell.exe" for visual studio was still running when I checked from the task manager. After I ended the process visual studio 2019 opened normal.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart the system,Its worked for me.

Comment: That was already suggested in another answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002833/1975002

Answer (score 1):

On task manager, kill "Visual Studio Installer". This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

[image: Process hacker]

It is Extension auto-update processing is running. You can either kill them or wait until they finished (recommended)

Answer (score 0):

Launch [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) and kill the Windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio 2017**, I had to end these processes:

- Visual Studio 2017
- TFS Power Tool Shell Extension

and then I could start VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

You can lunch [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_manager) or Process Hacker and terminate [VSSVC.exe](https://www.file.net/process/vssvc.exe.html). It is part of the Shadow Copy service which is utilized by system restore as well as system file protection and the "previous file version" feature, but may cause problems.
Restore points are created automatically during system changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I opened **Visual Studio Installer** and saw that it said

> Set up failed. Click retry to continue.

Once I reinstalled the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Visual Studio got closed automatically itself without asking any confirmation or showing warning.

Don't stop the process. Wait for 5 or 10 minutes. Visual studio will automatically start itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using 2019 version.

I think the **installation is going on in the background**. It opens after a while. If there is a missing package by looking through the Installer, you can try to install it as well.

Answer (score -1):

Launch [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) and end any process related to Visual Studio.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12871062)

Comment: @abarisone i was facing the same issue . But When i ended process relating to Visual studio  and launched visual studio it worked form me.

Answer (score -1):

In my task manager there is process for visual studio 2012 update i End that process and my VS 2015 working fine... Go to Task Manager and look for any(version) VS update process and just End that process.